# Un archivo .jar de la carpeta target se puede borrar?

Tags: java, maven

Tengo que subir un trabajo y excede los MB que acepta el buzón. Entonces quería saber si un archivo `.jar` que esta en la carpeta target se puede borrar y el proyecto sigue funcionando cuando el profesor lo compile.

Os dejo unas captura de pantalla con el archivo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El target es lo que se genera después de hacer build a tu proyecto. Si a tu maestro el envías el fuente(las classes .java) no tendrá problemas porque al compilar se hará la carpeta target.

Comment: oki entonces la carpeta la puedo borrar sin problema no ?muchas gracias

Comment: Así es, la puedes borrar. Incluso puedes borrarla y volver a compilar el proyecto para que veas que pasa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La carpeta `./target` es generada por Maven al compilar todo el proyecto, con lo que no pasa nada si la borras entera. La próxima vez que compiles el proyecto se autogenerará de nuevo.

Es una de las carpetas que automáticamente deben estar ignoradas por cualquier sistema de control de versiones de código (git, SVN, Mercurial...) porque son recursos *derivados* (generados a partir del código fuente).

Como nota final: `mvn clean` es el comando para borrar dicha carpeta.